# readHTMLTable function not able to extract the html table

Tags: r, analytics, rselenium

I would like to extract the table (table 4) from the URL "http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/oilnaturalgascorporation/profit-loss/IP02".  The catch is that I will have to use RSelenium

Now here is the code I am using:

```
remDr$navigate(URL)
doc<-htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
x<-readHTMLTable(doc)
```

The above code is not able to extract the table 4.  However when I do not use Rselenium like below, I am able to extract the table easily

```
download.file(URL,'quote.html')
doc<-htmlParse('quote.html')
x<-readHTMLTable(doc,which=5)
```

Please let me the solution as I have been stuck on this part for a month now.  Appreciate your suggestions

Comment: Why do you have to use RSelenium if it works just fine without it? Also, why does the `download.file` version specify `quote.html` but the RSelenium version does not? Are you sure the `[[1]]` index is returning the full HTML for the page?

Comment: RSelenium is useful for dynamically loaded webpages which is essential for my project.  Can you provide me the code which uses RSelenium and can extract the table under consideration

Comment: In this URL there are certain dynamic pages that uses AjaX.  The page content changes while the URL remains the same.  For example, if you click "Previous Years".  In short, download(URL,'qoute.html') will keep loading the initial page and hence RSelenium is necessary to browse into the dynamic pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  In my case, I had to first navigate to the inner frame (boxBg1) before I could extract the outer html and then use readHtmlTable function.  It works fine now.  Will post in case I run into a similar issue in the future

Answer (score 1):

I think it works fine. The table you were able to get using download.file can also be gotten by using the following code for RSelenium

```
readHTMLTable(htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource(),asText=TRUE),header=TRUE,which=6)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with more or less the same issue:  I'm trying to come up with a solution that doesn't use htmlParse:  for example (after navigating to the page):
table <- remDr$findElements(using = "tag name", value = "table"))

You might have to use css or xpath on yours, next step I'm still working on.

I finally got a table downloaded into a nice little data frame,  It seems easy when you get it figured out.  Using the help page from the XML package:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
u <- 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp'
doc <- htmlParse(u)
tableNodes <- getNodeSet(do9c, "//table")
tb <- readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[1]])
```